# Problem with proving the closure of a connected set is connected

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the closure of a connected set is connected, and from my research, it appears that my method is different from the typical method to prove this. My proof is:

*If a set $E$ is connected, then $E$ is open and closed under the relative topology induced on $E$. Thus $E = \bar{E}$, for $E$ is closed, so $\bar{E}$ is connected.*

This proof doesn't seem right, for I imagine a similar "proof" could show that the interior of a connected set is connected, which is false. However, I cannot find the particular spot where this proof falls apart.

Where do I make a false statement? Thank you.

Comment: The closure of $E$ is not the same as the closure of $E$ in the relative topology.

Comment: @John Griffin That makes sense. Thanks! Now... how to close a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $E \subset X$ connected.
In the **subspace topology**, $E$ is open and closed. However, when we speak of the "closure of E", we mean the intersection of all closed subsets of $X$, so you want to work in the topology of $X$ rather than the subspace topology.